# Which jquery version should be use for jPrompt?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function SetParam(e) {
    jPrompt('Enter a new parameter value .', '', 'Parameter Value', function (r) {
        if (r) ciSendCommand.PerformCallback("SetParam /" + e + "/" + r);
    });
}
```

I get this error in Chrome Console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: jPrompt is not defined`.

And that alert box does not display when I click button.

I used these jQuery versions.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: `jPrompt` is not part of jQuery. All jQuery functions have names like `$.something`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jPrompt` is not built into `jQuery`, it comes from the jQuery Alert Dialogs Plugin. You can get it from here:

http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/

There's no documentation. I looked in the comments in the source code, it doesn't say what version of jQuery it requires.

Comment: Solved Sir.Thank you.It needs jquery.alerts.js